# How to print the left and right sub-array before displaying the final merge sorted array?

Tags: c

This is what I have so far
https://notepad.vn/lvqrsmz99

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdio.h> 
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
{ 
    int i, j, k; 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 =  r - m; 

    int L[n1], R[n2]; 

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j]; 

    i = 0;  
    j = 0; 
    k = l; 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
    { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
        { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 

    while (i < n1) 
    { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 
    while (j < n2) 
    { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
} 
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l < r) 
    { 
        int m = l+(r-l)/2; 

        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
} 

void printArray(int A[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", A[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[20];
    int i,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printArray(arr, n); 
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1); 
    printf("\nSorted array is \n"); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

This is what I need to print prior the final sorted array:

3

14

3 14

1

12

5

1 3 14

5 12

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code.it is better than external link.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't "format as a code"... I don't quite understand the editor box

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Forgot to clarify the inputs, its the size of the array followed by an unsorted array

Comment: A `scanf` used without checking the **return** is an invitation for *Undefined Behavior* (and more often than not an infinite loop...)

Answer (score 1):

Noobie, there is a pretty good hint about where the "merge" is taking place in your code. That would provide a perfect place to look at the left and right sub-arrays before the merge.

If you look at the `merge()` function, you see the left and right sub-arrays being populated in the following code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];
```

With a little creativity, you could output the sub-arrays as they are being filled to obtain your desired output, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
        printf (" %d", L[i]); 
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]; 
        printf (" %d", R[j]); 
    }
    putchar ('\n');
```

(you could even add an additional `putchar ('\n');` after your first call to `printArray (arr, n);` to format the output a bit nicer)

**Example Use/Output**

When implemented, your output would be:

```
$ echo "5 3 14 1 12 5" | ./bin/mergeprn
3 14 1 12 5

 3
 14
 3 14
 1
 12
 5
 1 3 14
 5 12

Sorted array is
1 3 5 12 14
```

(the input values were gleaned from your question)

**Other Issues**

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where absolutely required like with the `scanf` *field-width* modifier). Instead, If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more), or use a global `enum` to do the same thing. That way you have one single place at the top of your code to change things if needed and you don't have to go picking through your declarations or loop limits to change things. E.g.

```
#define MAXA 20
...
    int arr[MAXA] = {0};    /* always initialize arrays */
```

**Always Validate `scanf` Return**

Any time you are using `scanf` you must **validate** the **return** or you are just asking for *Undefined Behavior* in the event of a *matching* or *input* failure. It doesn't take much more effort, but will save you a world of grief, e.g.

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid array size\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (n > MAXA) {  /* protect your array bounds */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: array size exceeds bound '%d'\n", MAXA);
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 2) {     /* make sure you have something to sort */
        fputs ("error, 'n' less than 2, nothing to sort\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (scanf ("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input 'arr[%d]'\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
```

Now you can rest assured you are processing valid input, and not some accidental character that causes a *matching failure* and *Undefined Behavior* in your code.

Comment: Sure, look at the additions as well. Start with good habits and you will avoid the number of times you end up beating your head into a wall trying to figure out where things went wrong (it will still happen, but the number of times will be greatly reduced `:)`

Comment: How can I avoid the display of the unsorted array?

Comment: Remove the first `printArray (arr, n);`

Comment: Aka 3 14 1 12 5

Comment: I'm going to let you in on a secret of how to really advance your understanding in C (or any other programming language), and it involves a duck.. Really! Take a look at [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... No kidding, it really helps `:)` If you take things line-by-line, and character-by-character, you will start to understand the programming at a much deeper level. Much deeper than [Geeks Merge Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)

Comment: Stack Overflow provides [**The Definitive C Book Guide and List**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help facilitate just this type of learning. Though there has been a spat over whether to continue the page, it still contains valuable information. The best advice I can give you on learning C is simply to SLOW  DOWN. There is no better language to learn, but there is a LOT to learn. You never really finish learning C, it is more a journey than a pit-stop. So slow-down and enjoy the ride - the learning will come it you take it that way.